# Cassandra or PostgreSQL: High volume of Inserts per minute

Tags: database, postgresql, cassandra

Here is my scenario:

1. I've **100,000+ tables**.
2. I've to make inserts in each table every minute, i.e. **100,000+ inserts per minute ALL in separate tables**.
3. Data loss doesn't matter much but speed and cost does.
4. Insertion fields would be id, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, timestamp.

Please let me know which database would be faster and cheaper for this case.

Comment: A single node of both pg and Cassandra will handle 100k inserts per minute (Postgres has a bulk Copy capability although that's one table). I would lean toward Cassandra as you say data loss isn't important, and Cassandra will ultimately scale beyond PG. But 100k tables? Wow

Answer (score 11):

Cassandra may face serious scalability issues with 100,000 separate tables. 100,000 separate tables means a multiple of 100,000 open files (so you'll need to make sure your kernel is configured to allow so many open files), 100,000 memtables (where the last modifications to each table are temporarily kept in memory) so you'll need a lot of memory.

An alternative way to do something like this in Cassandra is to have *one* table, with 100,000 different partitions (which is the Cassandra name for wide rows). Each minute you'd be adding one further row (a small entry) to each of the existing partitions. To avoid partitions growing huge after, say, months of adding entries, what one normally does is to start a new partition every, say, week (each week has about 10,000 minutes). In Cassandra modelling this is often called "time series data".

In your question, you only mentioned *writing* data, and not reading it. Assuming this is not an oversight, and you really care more about the write performance and not read performance, then Cassandra is a good fit because it is especially fast for writes. If you absolutely care about speed and performance-per-dollar, you should also take a look at **Scylla**, a re-implementation of Cassandra in C++.

Comment: This exactly defines our purpose. Cost is the main factor that we're trying to control right now. We're developing website with Go libs and using C for background jobs and hardware which are giving really amazing results on a single machine. We don't have a strong hold on database systems and that's why we're confused. Scylla seems very promising but it has a small community right now. Now, we are thinking to test all these systems to figure out the best performing system for us. Thanks a lot for writing in such detail.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like data model fits to time series model. TimeScaleDB may handle your model with new distributed model. The tables would be just one more indexed field. I.e. keep data in time order, enable compression. May consider different types of index not restrict yourself to B-trees only.

Our finance data tests showed amazing compression ratios - specially if all tables have similar data for close time periods e.g. cumulative and scaled values with 3-4k instruments. Didn't try with 100k but may consider do some benchmarks and see where is limit and in case of steep degradation shard to different machine/cluster.

Maintenance may be bit problematic if one decide to manage multiple manually shared servers, but single box can do cost magic in comparison to modern clusters. Multiple powerful isolated boxes  can be used if data loss can be tolerated e.g. replayed from different source in reasonable time (like efficient market data replay from archives)